# How to set left/right margin to QGridlayout cell in qt?

Tags: windows, macos, qt

How can I set left/right margin to a qgridlayout cell in Qt? I have tried setSpacing and setContentmargin but they do not set margin for cell but for QGridlayout.

Comment: Sorry just to make it superclear, you have something like a QPushButton inside a QGridLayout cell and you want to set the empty space between the button border and the actual cell border ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you'd probably want a layout (such as `QHorizontalLayout` or another `QGridLayout`) within the outer `QGridLayout`.

You could also use horizontal spacers, but those would have to be given a layout themselves, thus having again an outside layout and inside layout per cell.

In the inner layout, you will call `setAlignment( Qt::AlignLeft )` or `Qt::AlignRight` in conjunction with `setHorizontalSpacing()`. Then you can set the minimum size of the inner QWidget to determine the opposite margin.